# How to display an entry alert in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to show an alert with an entry inside it, as I can see it in a lot of apps, but I could'n t find a solution for now (neither custom renders)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UserDialogs libary](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)

After initialization simply use:

```
UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("message")
```

Comment: Thanks, it was easy <3

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in multiple ways. Lets say if you have your own UI and the Entry field. Then you can create the Popup Page and Display that Popup Page whenever necessary for the User Input. If you want to use Popup Page (best - only if you have requirements to have your own style of prompt):

```
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup
```

If you have very simple requirement of only Showing the Entry Field the use :

```
https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs
```

Since this is very common question and have all the resources online. Please go through the websites above have all the examples you can look into. Please let me know if you still need any more help.